# Request: Does notion of natural density $1$ with specified lower bound already exist

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$. Then one can look at the function $f(n)=|\{0,...,n\}\setminus A|$ ($|S|$ denoting the cardinality of $S$ ). I am interested in the case when $f(n)\leq Cn^\alpha$ with $C>0$ and $\alpha<1$. In this case $A$ obviously has natural density $1$. My question is: Is there already a name for this concept and if not how one "should" call sets with this property. Edit: I am mainly interested in the first part of the question, the second part is only included in case someone thinks they have a good idea. It goes without saying that I will come up with my own terminology if I don't get advice here.

I use sets with this property a lot in a work of mine, so I do need some useful name for it, since spelling it out each time seems bad practice. So the point of my question is to avoid the situation where I choose a name for it and then someone tells me that this concept has already been used multiple times and there already exist a standard name for it. As it is hard to search for an answer to my question I am asking it here in case someone has been working with this notion before. Edit: I am posting this question as density notions on the natural numbers are usually not in my area of research (I have been working in mathematical research for some years now) and I believe that there is a non-zero probability this notion has shown up before. As to why I believe this - as was asked in the existing answer - I can only say that this a hunch. What else could it be?

The reason why these sets are interesting for me is that they have the following property: For $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, $a\in \mathbb{N}$, $K\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon>0$ consider the set $F(A,\epsilon,a,K)=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid\forall 0\leq k\leq \epsilon\log n\forall i\leq K a^k : na^k+i\in A\}$. Then if $A$ has the above property and $\epsilon>0$ is small enough, then $F(A,\epsilon,a,K)$ has this property as well.

Edit: I want to protest against the fact that this question has been closed. I don't know if this is the right place to do so, so if this should be posted elsewhere let me know.

My question has the form:

I came across notion $P$ and I use it in my work. I believe there is a small probability that it occurred before. I think it is bad practice to use new notation for old concepts. I did not find it in the literature thus I am hoping that someone here might be of help.

I see that this is not a very typical question to be asked here, but I believe that it falls well within the range of perfectly fine things to ask on this site. So I don't see any rational reason to close the question.

Furthermore, I want to call out the imho unacceptable way this question was met by the community (I do this because I think it is important to call out problematic behavior. I hope other people share my conviction that we should treat each other fairly and humanely on this platform): The only answer labeled the post as "a bad question, because it doesn't really matter if there is a name for sets with this specific property, as the property isn't sufficiently interesting to warrant a name being described to it". Obviously to me this notion has some interest, otherwise I wouldn't have asked. Personal aesthetic beliefs should not be the guideline to label question as bad. I was also asked to provide more background on why I think this notion is interesting. I did this (it is a technical notion that I need for a central lemma) to the effect that now it was assumed that the background was "contrived [...] to make your sets seem more interesting...". To me this is an attempt to bully and that is why I am calling it out in the hope that people agree that this should not be the way we treat each other on this site. I am new to this site so I hope I was just unlucky and this is not a systemic issue. I think that the principle of charity should be applied to any post in sense it should be assumed that people have good reasons to ask their questions here and have put some effort into solving the issue beforehand.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. There might be a name for the case $|[0\ldots n]\cap A|\le Cn^\alpha$ instead of for the case $|[0\ldots n]\cap A|\ge n-Cn^\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bad question, because it doesn't really matter if there is a name for sets with this specific property, as the property isn't sufficiently interesting to warrant a name being described to it.

I also don't see how the sets you describe are "refined notions of natural density."

*Looking for* names of sets with particular properties seems like a fruitless activity (unless the property is sufficiently "interesting"), as it is very easy to come up with infinitely many distinct properties that sets can have, and ask, "do sets with this property have a name?" each and every time. Most properties of such sets will not have a name. So just describe the property mathematically if you don't know the name. If then someone informs you of/you stumble across in a paper the name that exists for that property then you can amend your work/knowledge accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use sets with this property a lot in a work of mine, so I do need some useful name for it, since spelling it out each time seems bad practice. So the point of my question is to avoid the situation where I choose a name for it and then someone tells me that this concept has already been used multiple times and there already exist a standard name for it. As it is hard to search for an answer to my question I am asking it here in case someone has been working with this notion before.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe your comment should be the second paragraph in your question. Out of interest, what is interesting about those sets? Why are you studying them (maybe include this in your question also)?

Comment: I edited the question. I am calling it a refined notion of natural densitiy, because sets with this property have natural density $1$, but not all sets with natural densitiy $1$ have this property.

Comment: Are you in a position to say that this notion is not sufficiently interesting to warrant a name of its own? In the sense that noone has ever looked at it and given it a name? Or is this statement just an expression of your personal opinion? Please clarify, because if the first alternative applies then that would answer my question.

Comment: It is more my opinion. And it is also my opinion that one should not waste time asking questions looking for names of things where it doesn't matter that much if there is or isn't a name. Get on with the maths and if there is a name for that thing, someone will inform you sooner or later about it. I don't think the sets you are describing are particularly interesting in and of themselves, even within the context of your function $F.$ In fact, I think your function $F$ is more of a contrived function to make your sets *seem* more interesting...

Comment: My advice is to stop wasting time caring about if someone has given a name to something and get on with the maths. You can even say that your sets "Satisfy Property $1.1$" of the article/paper you are writing. I also still don't see how your sets are a *refined* notion of "natural density". They are just sets of density $1$ with sets of density $0$ with specific property removed. So what?

Comment: Your answers have not been helpful. You repeatedly failed to acknowledge the point of my question even after I made it perfectly clear that it is not about you or anyone else finding this notion interesting. This is inacceptable. Thus you disqualify as a discourse partner and until you show signs of goodwill I will not respond to any of your replies.

Comment: Ok. Sorry I wasn't helpful. Hopefully someone else can be more helpful!